# React jest test throws 'Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, props})"

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a class component. When i'm writing an unit test for it, I get an error with this message

```
"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, props}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."
```

Below is my component

```
export class IncidentCloseFormModal extends React.Component<Props, State> {
public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <Modal
        isOpen={this.props.visible}
        title={Messages.contactSupport.closeConfirmation.closeRequest()}
        closeHandler={this.props.onRequestCancellation}
        closeLinkText={Messages.contactSupport.labels.cancel()}
      >
        <SpinnerModal forceOpen={this.state.submitDisabled}/>
        <Form
          onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
          validator={this.validate}
        >
          {this.props.visible && !!this.props.errorMessage ?
            this.props.errorMessage : null
          }
          <p>{Messages.contactSupport.closeConfirmation.confirmation(this.props.incidentId)}</p>
          <small><b>{Messages.contactSupport.closeConfirmation.descriptionHeading()}</b></small>
          <Field
            fieldName={DescriptionFieldName}
            hint={<DescriptionHint /> as any}
          >
              <Textarea
                onChange={this.onDescriptionChange}
                rows={3}
                value={this.state.description}
              />
           
          </Field>

          <>
            <Button
              type={ButtonType.Submit}
              label="Request to Close"
            >
              Request to Close
            </Button>
          </>
        </Form>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
};
```

and my test

```
import { createMock } from "ts-auto-mock";
interface Props {
  visible: boolean;
  incidentId: string;
  incident?: Incident;
  onRequestSubmission: (description: string) => void;
  onRequestCancellation: () => void;
  errorMessage: JSX.Element;
}
describe("IncidentCloseForm tests", () => {
  let mock: Props;
   beforeEach(() => {
    mock = createMock<Props>();
  });
  it("IncidentCloseForm", async () => {
    mock.visible = true;
    const { container} = render(
      <IncidentCloseFormModal {...mock} />,
    );
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

I'm not able to figure out whats going wrong with this error message. Any help in giving pointers on how to solve this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: I've never seen an access modifier or return type on the render method before, have you tried making the signature `render() { return ( ... )};`?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown what properties `mock` has.

Comment: Yeah @daly, thats because its a class component and it requires a access modifier.

Comment: @EstusFlask, updated the question with mock details.

Comment: It's unknown what `createMock` is.

Comment: @EstusFlask, its mock from "ts-auto-mock";

Comment: For what it's worth this error usually means that you've passed the component class itself rather than a rendered instance of it. The difference between `<div>{SomeComponentClass}</div>` and `<div><SomeComponentClass /></div>`.

Comment: Then that's the problem. The error suggests that it provides bogus element that conforms to JSX.Element as errorMessage instead of real React element. Don't use it for this.

Comment: Thanks @rayhatfield  that worked

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask